# Should we be vegan?

Tags: food, vegetarianism

I am non-vegetarian but since reading through Buddhist scriptures, I felt like going towards Vegan would be prefered approach in order to follow and know Buddhism.

Please guide me on this dilemma.

Regards

Comment: I think some Buddhists are and some aren't -- and that it may vary depending on which school (or 'tradition') of Buddhism -- also depending on whether vegan food is available! There are a lot of existing topics tagged  [tag:vegetarianism] -- I'm not sure what you're asking that is different from what's been asked already?

Comment: There is a salient difference between being a vegetarian and being a vegan in the modern world. Vegetarianism is a dietary restriction meant to reduce harm to animals who are raised and slaughtered for their flesh. Veganism, on the other hand, is a way of life that includes a cuisine in which all animal-derived products are left out, and alternative plant-based means to arrive at the same texture, taste, and presentation are used. It goes beyond that to a total eradication of the use of animals for any human activity that can cause harm to the animal--eg, no leather, circuses or killing…

Comment: "Pure and earnest bhikshus, if they are true and sincere, will never wear clothing made of silk, nor wear boots made of leather because it involves the taking of life. Neither will they indulge in eating milk or cheese because thereby they are depriving the young animals of that which rightly belongs to them." Surangama Sutra, Chap Two, "Importance of Keeping the Precepts" https://medium.com/p/e84c1abb029b